# JSF - xhtml inside the <p:outputPanel> needs to be refreshed for each ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Here is the code that I am working with

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west" size="310" header="Filter Criteria"
resizable="true" collapsible="true" gutter="1" effect="drop"><p:outputPanel id="sysdetfilterDisplay"><ui:include src="/faces/systemdetailsfilter.xhtml">
</p:outputPanel></p:layoutUnit><p:layoutUnit position="center">
<p:outputPanel id="contentDisplay"><ui:include src="/faces/systemdetailsinfo.xhtml" ><ui:include src="/faces/comment.xhtml">
<p:outputPanel>
```

Inside the systemdetailsfilter.xhtml I am having an datatable, when i click each row in the data table, the corresponding data's for the each row is showed in the another xhtml which is systemdetailsinfo.xhtml inside another  outputpanel in another layoutunit as given above.

**Actual behvaiour:**

My problem is there is an edit button inside the systemdetailsinfo.xhtml which is use it to  edit the data which will show data's for a specific row selected in the datatable as i said earlier.

when i search and click another row in the datatable the  id="contentDisplay" is still showing the fields as already edited [since i have clicked the edit button for the previous row which I selected earlier and I did not clicked the edit button for the current row for which the data is showing right now ]and the page in the right side is not refreshing when i click each row in the datatable.

here is the ajax call i have added inside the datatable.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{systemDetailsBean.onRowSelect}"  
update=":contentDisplay :growl :error">
```

**Expceted behvaiour:**
The systemdetailsinfo.xhtml  should get refreshed for each time when I click a different rows in the datatable.

Comment: So- it doesn't work? Or you want the code to look better? What is the question?

Comment: Contents are showing in the systemdetailsinfo.xhtml which is inside the outputpanel.But when i click the edit button for the showed content the edited fields remained edited though I clicked another Row in the datatable[but the new data's are shown with edited mode and its suppose to be shown as not editable].Its suppose to get refreshed.OR how do I refresh the systemdetailsinfo.xhtml considering the above code for clicking each row in the datatable

Comment: Depending on the version of primefaces you are using, you can define **autoUpdate="true"** in your outputPanel.